# IOS how different put down two fingers at one time and put down two fingers one by one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, touch-event

On IOS what is the difference between putting down two fingers at one time and putting down two fingers one by one?

Can I use `UIGesturerecognizer` to detect different touch-events? And how do I tell them apart?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference purely because there is no such thing as putting two fingers down at once.

No matter how closely you put down two fingers there will always be a time difference between the first and second touch.

In you Gesture Recognizer you have to program for this and work out what a suitable time difference is to make two separate touches into a single "two-touch" gesture.

For instance, you might say that 0.5 seconds is a suitable maximum between touches. If two touches land within 0.5 seconds then they are the same gesture but if they are more than 0.5 seconds apart then they are not.

Comment: Thank you,what i really want to know is the difference between "putting down two fingers and then sliding" and "putting down one finger and then sliding  ,last putting down the other finger sliding together ".Sorry ,my English is not good ,i don't know if i have explain clear.